# Loop through number of days in hijri month

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar, hijri

I am using a class to convert Gregorian to Hijri dates.

```
hdate = hijriToGreg(y, m, d);
```

How do I loop through this to get the number of days in the hijri month?

In other words, how can I get the last day of the hijri month?

Comment: Is using an existing API an option? JodaTime is an excellent time/date API for Java, and it includes an IslamicChronology. And, conversion is simple with Joda, and built in. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @CharlieCollins, I'll have to start from scratch if I choose to use Joda.